# WebkitDFB with LiTE toolkit - Tab key not captured in webview

Tags: webkit, directfb

I'm trying to use WebkitDFB r124228 tree.

The WebView cannot receive Tab key events. I'm not sure why? I tried handling the key event in LiTE program and it seems to capture TAB key. But the Javascript code in WebView couldn't capture TAB key. All other keys, even shift, ctrl and alt modifiers are captured.

I'm using the built-in program Tools/lite_web/main.c

Any help is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In LiTE toolkit, they are trying to handle the DIKI_TAB key to change focus of the Lite_Box element to next sibling of the window. So there the event is consumed.

But actually the `focus_traverse` operation doesn't do anything yet. So instead of consuming the event I made it pass through the `focus_traverse` and then continue on to webview event handler.

I'm using LiTE-0.8.10.

Source file: *lite/window.c +2423*

Modify `return focus_traverse(window);`

to `focus_traverse(window);`

It is not fixed in later versions of LiTE Toolkit as well.